# How do I add Session support to WebAPI in .Net 4.5

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

In previous versions I could add a route handler with IRequiresSessionState, as explained here:

http://forums.asp.net/post/4884822.aspx

Since the last version the MapHttpRoute doesn't have a RouteHandler.

I already know that HTTP should be stateless, so I understand this behaviour as default, but still I need this workaround for my specific scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question has been [answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api/9594406#9594406)

Comment: Thanks! I used the source of that response to implement the workaround and it worked. http://forums.asp.net/t/1773026.aspx/1