# ASP.NET MVC Web Api 4.5 Session state

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, session-state

I found solutions to add Session State for web api 4.0. But I have not found one for 4.5.
Could some one point how to accomplish this?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api) help?

Comment: No, that links take me to a page where i can not find the code

Answer (score 3):

[Use this solutions](http://techhasnoboundary.blogspot.be/2012/03/mvc-4-web-api-access-session.html):

But instead of the following code in de webapiconfig

`var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...`

use the RoutTable class

`var route = RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...`

Answer (score 3):

You can test the incoming request using RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData to determine whether it is an Web API request:

```
    protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
        // WebApi SessionState
        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
        if (routeData != null && routeData.RouteHandler is HttpControllerRouteHandler)
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
    }
```