# How can we access a session variable in a controller which is defined in an api controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have defined a session variable in Api controller

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["_USBDocuments"] = folders;
```

Now, i want to access the session variable which is defined in api controller in the normal controller.

Is it possible to access like this? If it is possible then what is the way to access it?

Thank You.

Comment: `var folders = HttpContext.Current.Session["_USBDocuments"];`

Comment: If they are in the same HttpContext then yes above will work.

Comment: Thank You But what is meant by same HTTPContext

Comment: You might want to take a look on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 0):

By design, you are not supposed to use Session in Web API. It defeats the purpose of it being **stateless**. But if you still want to access Session in an Api Controller, you can add the following function in your Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
    HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```