# Sencha ExtJS integrating with existing asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, extjs, extjs6

Our existing product is in Asp.net web form, as we are planning to migrate each page to Sencha ExtJS 6 with Asp.net Web Api, this migration will be stage by stage rather than in one shot. So technically we need to design a solution in a way to support all the new pages in ExtJS and still all the old pages should use Asp.net web forms.

Since we are very early stage of learning ExtJS, we dont have any expertise in this area.

We had come up with few solutions. Could anyone please advice and guide us in right direction. Let us know if you got any other better way of design this.

**Solution 1:** Add ExtJS app to existing web application.

***Cons:*** Implementation will be messy with web forms and ExtJS together.

**Solution 2:** Create separate ExtJS App for all the new pages and existing Asp.net webforms will call the ExtJS pages for few modules, and vice versa ExtJS will call the Asp.Net web forms for exisiting page access.

***Pro:*** No tweaking is required in the existing Asp.net web project, once all the pages has been migrated we can dispose the asp.net web project completely out of way.

***Cons:*** * Maintaining session state between ExtJS app and Asp.net web application.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK maintaining session state between the two frameworks should be no issue, as long as they are on the same IIS they can use the same cookies and stuff. There is no such thing as a fixed boundary between WebAPI and WebForms.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, here as per my solution 2 I will be having 2 applications, one is traditional web forms and another one is new Sencha ExtJS app. I believe we cannot share the session state across the applications even if it is in same IIS.

Comment: Please elaborate as to whether we refer to the same [session state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) as per Microsoft nomenclature. The server-side session state [can be accessed from WebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api).

Comment: which version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: Am not talking about session access from web api. Consider my ExtJS app will be hosted in same IIS as webforms app. But my Web API is in completely different IIS box. Lets take example(without WebAPI). just ExtJS application(contains page AppPage1) and WebForms application(contains page Form1).  Initially, Form1 wil be loaded(at this point of new session will be created for this user), On buttonclick event in form1, redirect to AppPage1. and redirect to Form1 from AppPage1 on another button click in AppPage1. Question is when we come back to AppPAge1 to Form1 will old session will be retained?

Comment: Am using ExtJS 6.0.1