# Session state variable usage in web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to use session variables in my web api non mvc application.

I have enabled session in global.aspx page as

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }
```

Now in my controller

```
public class AuthenticateController : ApiController
{
[Route("api/CheckLogin")]
public string AuthenticateUser(Models.Customer customer)
{

HttpContextBase context = null;
var httpContext = context as HttpContextBase;
httpContext.Session["username"] = "sa";

}
```

But I am getting null ref error.

How can I achieve this

Please help

Comment: Let me get this straight: you create a variable called `context`, set it equal to `null`, cast that null value as an `HttpContextBase`, and then try to use it?
At some point you have to actually set it equal to the current context, or at least set it to some non-null value. I.e. `context = HttpContext.Current;`.

Comment: You don't need the `HttpContextBase context = null;` line. And you need to check that httpContext is non null before using it. The `as` can return null if the object you're trying to cast is not of type HttpContextBase. After that, you'll need to check that username has been correctly set in the session. Debug it by checking that value for null, on retrieval from your Session object.

Comment: I did like this                                                                                                                       object context;
                if (Request.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_HttpContext", out context))
                {

                    var httpContext = context as HttpContextBase;
                    if (httpContext != null && httpContext.Session != null)
                    {
                        httpContext.Session["d"] = "sa";
                    }
                }

Answer (score -1):

Well the `context` is set to `null` . So basically you are executing `null.Session["username"]` ! But why do you need a session in this implementtaion. This is a REST service right ? Its supposed to be stateless.
See this excellent answer here : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api)