# Dynamic Entity Framework on Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-4

I am using web api project with  Entity framework  and i was planning to make the Entity Framework as dynamic one [ change the connection string at run time]

In a normal MVC application i did this like

```
public class ApiRepository
{
    public WebApiLabDbEntities dbContext; 
    public ApiRepository()
    {
        string connection_string = (string)(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Connection"]);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(connection_string))
        {
            dbContext = new WebApiLabDbEntities();
        }
        else
        {
            dbContext = new WebApiLabDbEntities(connection_string);
        }


    }

}
```

But in a webapi project i cant set the connection string in a session object like Session["Connection"]

So what is the alternative way to achieve the same? The web api is going to use token based authentication and the auth_token decides the connection string to be used.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to use Session in WebAPI. This is possible. Take this as example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api

Comment: I was planning to read access_token and based on it construct connection_string and keep it in some place like either session or append to request [ dont know is possible or not ] and then access from either Session or from Request object

Answer (score 0):

If your connection string depends on the authenticated user, then you should apply your logic based on current user Claims (e.g. using `Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal` and reading issued claims).

Of course this means that you should issue a claim that will make your Identity aware of the different connection strings.

This is a board topic and strongly depends on what kind of authentication, authorization and identity framework you are using behind the scenes, but this post could lead you towards the right direction: [ASP.NET Web API Claims Authorization with ASP.NET Identity 2.1 – Part 5](http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/)