# Webapi and Sessions

Tags: session, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to add sessionstate to my existing asp.net application.
I have added

**httpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required)**

to the global.asax file but each time i make a call to the api, a new session is created.

here is how i am trying to view the session

```
        var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;

        if (session != null)
        {
            if (session["TestSession"] == null)
            {
                session["TestSession"] = "Session Exists"
            }
            return "TestSession: " + session["TestSession"];
        }

        return ("No Session");
```

Just wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem, i am using a session state sqldatabase to store the session

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api

Comment: My code was based on that article, but it doesnt seem to be working for me.