# WEB API 2.0 (i can access Session Object but i can't access value of session.)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-web-api

First,I did not access HttpContext.Current.Session, and I added in below statement in global.asax.

```
  protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
  }
```

After that, i could access HttpContext.Current.Session and i set a value in Session object.

But I cant access my value in another action.

For example :

Account/Login

```
Session["User"]="User";
```

Account/BlaBla

```
Session["User"] is null;
```

Why couldn't i do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Session Using ASP.NET Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api

Comment: No it is not dublicate question, you see i tried these answers but did not solve my problem, i can access HtttpContext.Current.Session object i can set a Session but i can not acces value in another action.