# SessionStateBehavior.Required not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, session-state

I've tried the instruction [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api) to enable sessions on my API calls with a little change since I do not use the MVC WebApi but use an area instead. Here is my `Global.asax.cs`

```
...
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
    if (IsWebApiRequest())
    {
        HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
    }
}

private bool IsWebApiRequest()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith("/ws/");
}
```

And here is the code I use to call the web service from a *different web application*.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionReturn>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

**But whenever I make a call, the session always resets.** I even try to remove the checking if it is a `WebApiRequest()` and even add a `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Required)]` attribute to my api controller but to no avail. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?