# ASP Net Core 2.1 Session

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am currently developing an API in .Net Core 2.1
 with a client application in Vue 2 with Nuxt, and I have problems saving an object in session in ASP .Net.
I have reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317304/asp-net-core-2-1-session) and other links before asking this question, but nothing has been able to help me.
It turns out that I've tried it with Postman and if it works, but I do not understand why it does not work with my application.

This is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
// Add Database
// End Add Database
    services.AddCors(options => 
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", builder =>
    builder.AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyOrigin()
));
});
 services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    .AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1440);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc();
}
}
```

In my controller:

```
[Route("api/customer/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ClientController : ControllerBase { ...
```

... Get and set Session Var

```
var model = HttpContext.Session.GetString("User")
```

And other controller

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("User", "Hello World")
```

HttpContext  changes id every time I make a request for ajax, but postman does not change the Id and that's why I can recover the cookie.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong here `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    .AddDistributedMemoryCache();`
Change to  `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);`

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work for me. I do not understand why Postman works, but not on my website. Something has to do with the Cors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely need to set the [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) flag when making your AJAX request. That shouldn't be required for same-site requests, but you mentioned CORS and didn't specify that it was same-site. With jQuery, that just means adding it to `xhrFields` in your your AJAX options object:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

Other libraries may have a different methodology, but all should have some way of setting this flag on the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: OHHHH Thanks, 
Thank you very much, you have put an end to several days of suffering. For further references, I will leave the correct answer:
nuxt.config.js:
`/*
  ** Modules Config
  */
  axios: {
    credentials: true
  },`
In my Cors
`services.AddCors(opt =>
{
    opt.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", builder =>
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowCredentials()
                );
            })`

Comment: Is there any way to parameterize this URL of my application externally?
`http://localhost:3000`