# How to create a new session id in ASP.net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I have used below code to create session id in Asp.net.

```
var sessionManager = new  SessionIDManager();
var sessionId = sessionManager.CreateSessionID(HttpContext.Current);
```

Can somebody suggest how to do same functionality in asp.net core 3.1???

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the Session ID? As you know `SessionIDManager` is a ASP.Net full-framework class, so its not available, hence there is probably a newer & better way.

Just beware in ASP.NET core *2.1* that every request.. the session ID changes.. (HttpContex.Session.Id): here is the fix for that, read all 3 top answers:
[ASP.NET core 2.1 session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317304/asp-net-core-2-1-session)

Here's a **solution**, go ahead and set a SessionID yourself using the session:

```
Session.SetString("SessID", new Guid().ToString());
```

Comment: I don't believe that a Guid is cryptographically unique enough to be securely used as a session ID.