# MVC 5 app with Active Directory authentication failing Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, ldap

I have an MVC 5 web app that is set up to use Forms authentication as per this [this link](http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/)

It is successfully validating against LDAP (i.e., the call to `Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.RememberMe)` returns true) but when it redirects to the Index action of my HomeController, it is hitting the `[Authorize]` attribute and thinking that the user is not authorized for some reason, so it redirects to the login page again.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Strange thing is, it works as expected in MVC 4...

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution, I am experiencing this as well following the guide you provided.

Comment: I never did.  I just did it the "MVC 4" way and it has been working fine ever since.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the authentication cookie to the response something like this:

```
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie((model.UserName, model.RememberMe)
```

or you can do it manually like it's described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217105/how-can-i-manually-create-a-authentication-cookie-instead-of-the-default-method)