# ASP.NET CORE window and form authentication together

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-authentication

I am working on ASP.NET CORE MVC Application and I need to authenticate user on Active Directory/Window Authentication, but also using Form Authentication.

In Form Authentication, I need to provide mechanism for Super Admin User Credential which has specific user name and password. This is for purpose super admin account can everything on app but also not bound to any specific user.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Is form authentication enough for super admin authentication? Or both windows and form authentication are required?

Comment: no form is only for Super Admin where rest as user will be authenticated with Active Directory/ Window

Comment: If there was not going to be a local identity db and assuming cookies are being used could you manually create and sign in the user using a separate action method.  I was thinking about one of Brock Allen's post where he manually did this in a previous version of asp.net using Identity. https://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/ or where this was done on stack overflow here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217105/how-can-i-manually-create-a-authentication-cookie-instead-of-the-default-method