# ASP.NET OWIN OpenID Connect not creating user authentication

Tags: c#, owin, openid-connect, owin-middleware

I have an ASP.NET 4.6 web app that I'm trying to add OpenId Connect using OWIN.

I added my Owin startup class and everything appears to be configured correctly, but the problem I'm having is the ASP Identity/Authenticated user never gets created. I end up with an endless loop, where the OpenId callback page redirects back to the original page, which then redirects to the login page, etc.

Here is my startup class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {


     app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);


        app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login.aspx"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7)
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {                
            ClientId = _clientId,
            ClientSecret = _clientSecret,
            Authority = _authority,
            RedirectUri = _redirectUri, // LoginCallback
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:60624/Logout.aspx",

            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            Scope = "openid profile email",

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name"
            },

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    // Exchange code for access and ID tokens
                    var tokenClient = new TokenClient($"{_authority}/as/token.oauth2", _clientId, _clientSecret);

                    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, _redirectUri);
                    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                    }

                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient($"{_authority}/idp/userinfo.openid");
                    var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

                    var claims = new List<Claim>(userInfoResponse.Claims)
                      {
                        new Claim("id_token", tokenResponse.IdentityToken),
                        new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken)
                      };

                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaims(claims);



                    //// create the identity
                    //var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                    //{
                    //    IsPersistent = true
                    //}, identity);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the Login.aspx page:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
              new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Request["ReturnUrl"] ?? "Default.aspx" },
              OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }        
    }
```

The page flow goes like this:

1) Request: http://localhost:60624/Page.aspx
Response: 302 - redirect to Login.aspx

2) Request: http://localhost:60624/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2FPage.aspx
Response 302 - redirect to https://auth.myprovider.com

Some cookies set here on the response headers:

Set-Cookie: OpenIdConnect.nonce.KIsuj4RUmGKJIynLrkEScxBvGrZzkMo6ylZ%2F4lRknPM%3D=xxxxxxxxx; path=/; expires=Mon, 22-Apr-2019 14:12:00 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: OpenIdConnect.nonce.KIsuj4RUmGKJIynLrkEScxBvGrZzkMo6ylZ%2F4lRknPM%3D=yyyyyyyyy; expires=Mon, 22-Apr-2019 14:12:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

3) Auth provider, sign-in, and it 302 redirects to /LoginCallback

4) Request: http://localhost:60624/LoginCallback
Response 302 - redirect to /Page.aspx

Cookies that were set in step 2 are cleared here.

Set-Cookie: OpenIdConnect.nonce.KIsuj4RUmGKJIynLrkEScxBvGrZzkMo6ylZ%2F4lRknPM%3D=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: OpenIdConnect.nonce.KIsuj4RUmGKJIynLrkEScxBvGrZzkMo6ylZ%2F4lRknPM%3D=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/

5) Back to Page.aspx, user not authenticated; Goto step 1

I've done some debugging, and the AuthorizationCodeReceived fires on the Startup, and the backend successfully calls the User Info endpoint. I've tried to call System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn() from that Notification, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

At this point, I'm stuck. Why is the authentication cookie for the user identity not being set? It seems like this is supposed to happen automatically.  Am I supposed to manually create this myself? ([How can I manually create a authentication cookie instead of the default method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217105/how-can-i-manually-create-a-authentication-cookie-instead-of-the-default-method))

EDIT: After reviewing @**Zaxxon**'s reply, I was able to get it working. There were 2 things wrong in the AuthorizationCodeReceived notification

1. I needed to create the ClaimsIdentity. In my original code I submitted above, I had commented out this, but it was also incorrect.
2. I had to replace the AuthenticationTicket with a new one with the new identity I just created. Then add the claims to this new Identity.

Here is the working code:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimTypes.GivenName, ClaimTypes.Role);
 n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
 n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaims(claims);
```

Comment: The cookie already on the server may not be valid or expired.  I would use IE and delete all cookies and try again.  I think you are getting an exception and should exit code when the exception occurs instead of retrying.  Error 302 looks like it is some sort of Port Forwarding algorithm.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: There is no error. HTTP 302 is a normal redirect response in this process as it moves between flows of the pages. I'm not seeing any exception anywhere during this process, even after clearing cookies.

Comment: Are you seeing 200 OK?  I suspect you are getting exceptions and would add exception handlers.  Also would check Event Viewer to see if you have any errors.

Comment: I don't see 200 OK because the user is never authenticated. As I mention, after going through the auth flow, it repeats itself because the cookie is never set during the authentication. Where would I add an exception handler in the OWIN process?

Comment: You need to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and first confirm you are sending the request.  Once a request is sent to the server the server should send back a response with a status like 200 OK (or a failure status).  Right now from your description I'm not sure if the request is ever sent.  I also can't tell if this is secure (using SSL or TTLS) or non secure.  And then I can't tell if you are using http 1.0 (stream mode) or http 1.1 (chunk mode).  The server may not be running so from cmd.exe use > Netstat -a and verify there is a listener on port 60624.

Comment: My question includes all of the requests that are made. The are numbered 1-5. These came from Fiddler / Chrome dev tools. The responses are not 200 OK - they are 302, because they redirects are done by the OWIN / Auth provider process. Thanks for the help, but it sounds like you aren't too familiar with how Oauth/Owin process works.

Comment: The links are not reachable.  They are localhost which is on your computer and nobody else can  see them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, I had to get a Proof of Concept working for this a while back in VB.Net which was somewhat painful.  Here is my test code (i.e. not production code), which is based on some other C# internet examples I saw:

```
Imports System.Security.Claims
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports IdentityModel
Imports IdentityModel.Client
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Imports Owin

Partial Public Class Startup
    Private Shared _oAuthOptions As OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    Private Shared _publicClientId As String

    Private Shared _clientId As String
    Private Shared _clientSecret As String

    ' Enable the application to use OAuthAuthorization. You can then secure your Web APIs
    Shared Sub New()

        _clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OAuth:ClientID").ToString()
        _clientSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OAuth:SecretKey").ToString()

        PublicClientId = _clientId

        OAuthOptions = New OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() With {
            .TokenEndpointPath = New PathString("/Token"), 'New PathString("https://authtesteria.domain.com/as/token.oauth2"), ' 
            .AuthorizeEndpointPath = New PathString("/Account/Authorize"), 'New PathString("https://authtesteria.domain.com/as/authorization.oauth2"), '
            .Provider = New ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            .AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            .AllowInsecureHttp = True
        }
    End Sub

    Public Shared Property OAuthOptions() As OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        Get
            Return _oAuthOptions
        End Get
        Private Set
            _oAuthOptions = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Property PublicClientId() As String
        Get
            Return _publicClientId
        End Get
        Private Set
            _publicClientId = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
        ' Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf ApplicationDbContext.Create)
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationUserManager)(AddressOf ApplicationUserManager.Create)
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationSignInManager)(AddressOf ApplicationSignInManager.Create)

        ' Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        ' and to use a cookie to temporarily store inforation about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        ' Configure the sign in cookie
        ' OnValidateIdentity enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        ' This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
            .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
                .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(
                    validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))},
            .LoginPath = New PathString("/Account/Login")})


        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)

        ' Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))

        ' Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        ' Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        ' This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie)

        ' Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions)

        Dim controller As New AccountController()

        'Dim validator As OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator = New OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator()
        'validator.ShowPII = False

        Dim oidcAuth As New Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
            .ClientId = _clientId,
            .ClientSecret = _clientSecret,
            .Authority = "https://authtesteria.domain.com",
            .Notifications = New Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
                .RedirectToIdentityProvider = AddressOf OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                .MessageReceived = AddressOf OnMessageReceived,
                .SecurityTokenReceived = AddressOf OnSecurityTokenReceived,
                .SecurityTokenValidated = AddressOf OnSecurityTokenValidated,
                .AuthorizationCodeReceived = AddressOf OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                .AuthenticationFailed = AddressOf OnAuthenticationFailed
        }}
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcAuth)

    End Sub

    Private Function OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(arg As RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification(Of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
        Debug.WriteLine("*** RedirectToIdentityProvider")

        If arg.ProtocolMessage.RequestType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout Then
            Dim idTokenHint = arg.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token")

            If idTokenHint IsNot Nothing Then
                arg.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value
            End If
        End If
        Return Task.FromResult(0)
    End Function

    Private Function OnMessageReceived(arg As MessageReceivedNotification(Of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
        Debug.WriteLine("*** MessageReceived")
        Return Task.FromResult(0)
    End Function

    Private Function OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(arg As AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification) As Task
        Debug.WriteLine("*** AuthorizationCodeReceived")
        'Upon successful sign in, get & cache a token if you want here
        Return Task.FromResult(0)
    End Function

    Private Function OnAuthenticationFailed(arg As AuthenticationFailedNotification(Of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
        Debug.WriteLine("*** AuthenticationFailed")
        Return Task.FromResult(0)
    End Function

    Private Function OnSecurityTokenReceived(arg As SecurityTokenReceivedNotification(Of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
        Debug.WriteLine("*** SecurityTokenReceived")
        Return Task.FromResult(0)
    End Function

    Private Async Function OnSecurityTokenValidated(arg As SecurityTokenValidatedNotification(Of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
        Debug.WriteLine("*** SecurityTokenValidated")
        'Verify the user signing in should have access or not.  Here I just pass folk thru.
        Dim nid = New ClaimsIdentity(
              DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, 'arg.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
              ClaimTypes.GivenName,
              ClaimTypes.Role)

        Dim tokenClient = New TokenClient("https://authtesteria.domain.com/as/token.oauth2",
             _clientId,
             _clientSecret)

        Dim tokenResponse = Await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(arg.ProtocolMessage.Code, arg.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri)

        ' get userinfo data
        Dim userInfoClient = New IdentityModel.Client.UserInfoClient("https://authtesteria.domain.com/idp/userinfo.openid")

        Dim userInfo = Await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken)
        userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(Sub(ui) nid.AddClaim(New Claim(ui.Type, ui.Value)))

        '' keep the id_token for logout
        'nid.AddClaim(New Claim("id_token", arg.ProtocolMessage.IdToken))

        '' add access token for sample API
        'nid.AddClaim(New Claim("access_token", arg.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken))

        '' keep track of access token expiration
        'nid.AddClaim(New Claim("expires_at", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(Integer.Parse(arg.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()))

        '' add some other app specific claim
        'nid.AddClaim(New Claim("app_specific", "some data"))

        nid.AddClaim(New Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "group1"))

        arg.AuthenticationTicket = New AuthenticationTicket(nid, arg.AuthenticationTicket.Properties)
        arg.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = HttpContext.Current.Session("PageRedirect").ToString() 
    End Function
End Class
```

Now I trigger the login like so:

```
Private Sub SomePageName_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            Console.WriteLine(User.Identity.GetUserName())
        Else
            Session("PageRedirect") = Request.Url
            Response.Redirect("/")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

We have a few differences:

1. I use OnSecurityTokenValidated but I'm not sure if that matters or not
2. I populate a Session variable with the current page's Request.Url,
3. then utilize that in the startup in OnSecurityTokenValidated's notification parameter: arg.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = …  (see my code).

Hopefully this will be of some help.  Enjoy!

Comment: I was going to submit some edits to fix the syntax highlighting on your answer (force VB highlighting), but Stack Overflow claims the suggested edit queue is full. (_I'm wondering if that queue is specifically for this answer, question, or all of Stack Overflow..._)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't need to add anything to the `Notifications` in the Startup file at all.  I was missing this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() 
{
    CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
});
```

There's some bug in Katana that prevents cookies from getting saved properly, and so adding this one line of code fixed my problem after three days of looking!

Answer (score 0):

I set RedeemCode=True and SaveTokens=True and put this into notifications and I was finally able to get it to work.  All the examples didn't include this, and I'm not sure why, but maybe its required for code flow.  You don't have to re-add the claims, or it will duplicate them.

Also don't forget to set TokenValidationParameters NameClaimType="name" if you want User.Identity.Name to be filled automatically.

```
SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
            {
                var ctx = context.OwinContext;
                
                var applicationCookieIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity, null, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, null, null);
                ctx.Authentication.SignIn(applicationCookieIdentity);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
```